# camera2 api: after manual control white balance, it takes no effect when set back to 'auto' mode

Tags: android, android-camera2

First, I manually set the white balance using below code. It takes effect.

```html
RggbChannelVector rggbChannelVector = ColorTemperatureConverter.convertTemperatureToRggb((int)white_balance_temperature);
previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE, CameraMetadata.COLOR_CORRECTION_MODE_TRANSFORM_MATRIX);
previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.COLOR_CORRECTION_GAINS, rggbChannelVector);
```

Second, when I set back to CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO(or CONTROL_AWB_MODE_DAYLIGHT) mode, it's no effect

```js
previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AWB_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO);
```

on the other hand, if I haven't manual control the white balance, it takes effect when I set to CONTROL_AWB_MODE_AUTO or CONTROL_AWB_MODE_DAYLIGHT.

anyone knowns the reason? thanks very much.